# How to return user input using an api in Django views? i keep receiving an error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, django, web, django-views

this is my code for views.py. I would like the user input to replace the value for the 'q' key in the querstring dict.

```
def index(requests):
return render(requests, 'index.html')


def news(requests): 
  if requests.method == 'POST':
    search = 'POST'
    url = "https://google-finance4.p.rapidapi.com/search/"
    querystring[0] = search 

    querystring = {"q":"*airbnb*","hl":"en","gl":"US"}

    headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "my api key",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "google-finance4.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)

    return render(requests, 'news.html')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Error')
```

someapp/urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name ='home'),
    path('news/', views.news, name="news")
    
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('search.urls')), 
    path('news/', include('search.urls'))
    
]
```

templates/index.html

```
 <form>
        class="form-inline"
        method="POST"
        action="{{ 'news/' }}"
        name="news"
      >
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          {%csrf_token%}
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Crypto"
            name="search"
            style="width: 50%; display: block; margin: 0 auto"
          />
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md"
            type="submit"
            id="button-addon2"
          >
            Search
          </button>
```

templates/news.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Crypto Talk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{news.views}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am  I formatting my syntax in the h1 element incorrectly, would this even tell Django to place the response I am looking for in this h1 tag?

Comment: You are mixing Django's `request` and [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Rename your function argument to `request` (or anything other than `requests`)

Comment: should I be using Django's 'request'? because pip only lets you install 'requests'

Comment: *"Each view function takes an `HttpRequest` object as its first parameter, which is typically named `request`."* ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view))

Comment: ok so the error has went away but now I can not post the results of the search on to my html doc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question, maybe you meant another. Try:

search = requests.POST["search"] # name of input

Comment: probably put to comment section